# how do I generate random group names using lists

Tags: python, list, random

I can not figure out my mistake. Can someone help me?

We are supposed to create the lists outside of the function. then create an empty list inside a function. We should return 9 different names.

```
    first_names = ["Gabriel", "Reinhard", "Siebren"]
    last_names = ["Colomar", "Chase", "Vaswani"]

    def name_generator(first_names, last_names):
        full_name= ()

    import random

    for _ in range(9):
        full_name=random.choice(first_names)+" "+random.choice(last_names)
        full_name.append(full_name)
    group_string = ", ".join(full_name)
```

Comment: There are only 9 possible names; if you choose them randomly, it is very unlikely you won't have any duplicates.

Comment: I don't want any duplicates. How can I change that? maybe first_name + "" + random.choise(last_name)?

Comment: Then you should make a list of all 9 combinations and `shuffle` it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but that's not what was asked by the teacher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a variable `full_name` twice: once as a string to store a new name in, and once as the list.  This is closer to what you want:

```
    import random

    first_names = ["Gabriel", "Reinhard", "Siebren"]
    last_names = ["Colomar", "Chase", "Vaswani"]
    full_names = []

    for _ in range(9):
        new_name=random.choice(first_names)+" "+random.choice(last_names)
        full_names.append(new_name)
    group_string = ", ".join(full_names)
```

I'll note that I'd probably use `full_names` as plural version of the variable name too since it's a list of multiple things.

Comment: thanks. now it says full_name is not defined

Comment: i also don't know what the benefit is in creating an empty list beforehand :(

Comment: @Max I've updated it to define full_names (which I always switched too plural).  And I deleted your function that wasn't needed.  You may need to restructure for it to be acceptable if you need to use functions.

Comment: WRT empty list -- the "append" function for lists only works once a list has been created.  It's a function that is specific to the datatype in use.  Until `full_names` exists as a list, there is no way to call append on a non-existent datatype.

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I don't get it. 

But ill keep trying. :)

Comment: How does this prevent duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

This makes a list of all possible full names and then picks from what hasn't been taken yet one by one.

```
remaining = [(a,b) for a in range(len(first_names)) for b in range(len(last_names))]

full_name = []
while len(remaining)>0:
    (a,b) = random.choice(remaining)
    full_name.append(first_names[a] + " " + last_names[b])
    remaining.remove((a,b))
```